# Showing two spaces not isometrically isomorphic

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, isometry, direct-sum

Let $X$ be a real Banach space. Consider the direct sum $X\oplus X\oplus X$ with the norm $$\|(x,y,z)\|_1=\|x\|+\|y\|+\|z\|\text{ for all }x,y,z\in X.$$ I want to show that this space is not isometrically isomorphic to $X^*\oplus X^*\oplus X^*$ with the norm $$\|(x^*,y^*,z^*)\|_1=\|x^*\|+\|y^*\|+\|z^*\|\text{ for all }x^*,y^*,z^*\in X^*.$$

To answer this question, I want to know about the properties shared by isometrically isomorphic spaces. I know that the following properties are shared by two isometrically isomorphic spaces (there may be many more that I don't know):

1. Extreme points
2. Distance between subsets

together with the properties like completeness and other preserved by an isomorphism.

In this problem, I feel, it is possible to show that the closed unit ball of one of the spaces contains extreme points, but not the other. However I could not make any progress. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: separability is shared between isomorphic spaces. Look for separable Banach spaces whose dual is not separable.

Comment: Doesn't this fail when $X \simeq X^*$ are isometrically isomorphic? $(\mathbb{R}^n, \Vert \cdot \Vert_2)$ is an example.